# Is maps.google.com accessible from a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

maps.google.com's crossdomain.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
  SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control 
     permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can you confirm that this effectively means "**Access Denied**" for Silverlight (and Flash), since there are no elements 'allow'ing any kind of access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that Silverlight will not grant access to the domain given the content of this crossdomain.xml. I would still like an explanation of what the crossdomain.xml means, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

A Silverlight 4 Out-of-Browser application can ignore the crossdomain.xml policy file.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Google Maps?  Bing Maps has a great Silverlight Control.  There is a good [article about it on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight-4-Bing-Maps.aspx) as well as [a nice Interactive SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/).

If it has to be Google Maps, check out [the flagged answer in this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/8774.aspx) which references [another CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scrapbook/googlemap.aspx?select=2065351&df=100&forumid=323057&exp=0) that may be helpful.

Comment: Yep, gotta be google maps - I am using the geocoding API that's on that server, rather than working with tiles.